# How to force Visual Studio Designer to emit AutoScaleDimensions set to (6F, 13F) within the InitializeComponent function

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-designer

I have a System.Windows.Forms.UserControl. I have observed that Visual Studio Designer puts the following two lines (among others) within the InitializeComponent function:

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(192F, 192F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

Is there any way from the Designer to tell Visual Studio Designer to put the following line instead of (192F, 192F)?

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
```

I have looked at the UserControl properties from the designer and I am not able to see what is the property that makes VS Designer to put that line (6F, 13F). So how can I force VS Designer to put (6F, 13F) instead of (192F, 192F)?

Comment: Are you asking about how to change what the designer puts in for the `AutoScaleDimensions` property in the `YourUserControl.Designer.cs` file?  Or, are you asking about what it puts into the designer code for a form in which you user control has been inserted?  If the former, have you tried simply changing the values in the `YourUserControl.Designer.cs` file.  Yes, the designer "owns" that file and you aren't supposed to mess around in there.  However, if you are careful, you can edit things there (though sometimes, the edits don't stick).

Comment: @Flydog57 I mean the code that designer puts within the InitializeComponent method automatically in the YourUserControl.Designer,cs file. There it puts: this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(192F, 192F); It's not a good practice to touch things there manually because when you modifies someyhing in the designer this code is auto-generated again, so you lose the changes you manually did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [AutoScaleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to [Dpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), then you can set your custom [AutoScaleDimensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscaledimensions?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(192, 192);
    }
}
```

By default the automatic scaling of the control is Font and as soon as the font of the control is set (changed) the value of AutoScaleDimensions will reset.

Comment: I had scale set to 200% in Windows OS. After changing it to 100% and using AutoScaleMode = Font, Visual Studio Designer automatically adds the line AutoScaleDimensions set to (6F, 13F) in the InitializeComponents method in .Designer.cs. Also I must say I am using Microsoft Sans Serif 8.25pt. Also thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: `AutoScaleMode = Font`, then the control will [calculate AutoScaleSize based on the font](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ContainerControl.cs,79c2f55f6c180c75).